# Imbalanced Regression

Tags: keras, regression, imbalanced-data

I have a regression task where the output can be between 0 and 1. My data is very imbalanced with many 0 values (see picture). How can I deal with this type of problem and avoid that my model outputs 0 all the time? I would like to do this with Keras/Tensorflow if possible.

[image]

Comment: One of the most important requisites of machine learning is to have a dataset that describes your model. You could remove all the zeros data leaving a balanced number of ones and zeros, however i suspect that doing this you would have too less data...

Comment: Hm I see, of course. Unfortunate as I dont have time to rerecord my data.I'm dealing with a multiregression problem that has a lot of imbalances as I see now, so removing all of them would also remove the whole dataset. Thanks for you answer!